# EXTRACT INTO with multiple rows (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

this is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SANDBOX.DAILYVERIFY_DATE(TABLE_NAME regclass, DATE_DIFF INTEGER)
    RETURNS void AS $$
 DECLARE
RESULT BOOLEAN;
DATE DATE;
 BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'SELECT VORHANDENES_DATUM AS DATE, CASE WHEN DATUM IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END AS UPDATED FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT DATE VORHANDENES_DATUM FROM ' || TABLE_NAME ||
       ' WHERE DATE > CURRENT_DATE -14-'||DATE_DIFF|| '  
       ) A
 RIGHT JOIN
          (
  WITH compras AS (
    SELECT ( NOW() + (s::TEXT || '' day'')::INTERVAL )::TIMESTAMP(0) AS DATUM
    FROM generate_series(-14, -1, 1) AS s
)
SELECT DATUM::DATE
FROM compras)
              B
          ON DATUM = VORHANDENES_DATUM'
     INTO date,result;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', result;
      INSERT INTO SANDBOX.UPDATED_TODAY VALUES (TABLE_NAME, DATE, RESULT);
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It is supposed to upload rows into the table `SANDBOX.UPDATED_TODAY`, which contains table name, a `date` and a `boolean`.
The `boolean` shows, whether there was an entry for that date in the table. The whole part, which is inside of `EXECUTE ... INTO` works fine and gives me those days.

**However**, this code only inserts the first row of the query's result. What I want is that all 14 rows get inserted. Obviously, I need to change it into something like a loop or something completely different, but how exactly would that work?

Side note: I removed some unnecessary parts regarding those 2 parameters you can see. It does not have to do with that at all.

Comment: Do you actually need to use EXECUTE? The code shown in your question doesn't need to be in EXECUTE, but maybe your real code does?

Comment: Iám pretty sure you can rewrite this into `INSERT INTO SANDBOX.UPDATED_TODAY (TABLE_NAME, DATE, RESULT) SELECT VORHANDENES_DATUM AS DATE, CASE WHEN DATUM IS NULL THEN FALSE ....` And remove the complete `EXECUTE` clause like @eurotrash also more or less suggested

Comment: Well, my real code uses (like you can see in the parameters) the table name and a number which it uses inside the query. Therefore, I'm gonna upload the "real chunk" in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the INSERT statement inside the EXECUTE. You don't need the result of the SELECT for anything other than inserting it into that table, right? So just insert it directly as part of the same query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SANDBOX.DAILYVERIFY_DATE(TABLE_NAME regclass, DATE_DIFF INTEGER)
    RETURNS void AS 
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE
        'INSERT INTO SANDBOX.UPDATED_TODAY
        SELECT ' || QUOTE_LITERAL(TABLE_NAME) || ', VORHANDENES_DATUM, CASE WHEN DATUM IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT DATE VORHANDENES_DATUM FROM ' || TABLE_NAME ||
            ' WHERE DATE > CURRENT_DATE -14-'||DATE_DIFF|| '  
        ) A
        RIGHT JOIN (
            WITH compras AS (
                SELECT ( NOW() + (s::TEXT || '' day'')::INTERVAL )::TIMESTAMP(0) AS DATUM
                FROM generate_series(-14, -1, 1) AS s
            )
            SELECT DATUM::DATE
            FROM compras
        ) B
            ON DATUM = VORHANDENES_DATUM';
END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks, you did it again for me!

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to [loop through dynamic query results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) would be

```
FOR date, result IN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT ...'
LOOP
   INSERT INTO ...
END LOOP;
```